# How to access a class field values in its base class?

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to access the values in a class fields from its base class. how to do it? look at my code:

```
class MyBase(object):

    def p(self):
        members = [attr for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")]
        print members

class UserTest(MyBase):
    def __init__(self, name='', family='', age=''):
        self.name = name
        self.family = family
        self.age = age

a = UserTest(name='ehsan', family='shirzadi', age=29)
a.p()
```

Using above code, I can see variable names after execution of a.p(), but how to see their values? Please consider that I don't know the name of fields, so I can't use self.name in the base class

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  You can do, e.g., `print a.name` to see the `name` attribute.  You can also do `print self.name` from within `p`.  But making the base class depend on attributes from a subclass is usually not a good design.

Comment: Please consider that I don't know the name of fields, so I can't use self.name in the base class. what should I do?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got the value once when doing `callable(getattr(self, attr))` in `MyBase.p`. You can either use the same to get the value for the output:

```
class MyBase(object):
    def p(self):
        print [(attr, getattr(self, attr)) for attr in dir(self)
            if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith('__')]
```

or you can use [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) instead of [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

```
class MyBase(object):
    def p(self):
        print [(attr, value) for attr, value in vars(self).items()
            if not callable(value) and not attr.startswith('__')]
```

Both yield a result like:

```
[('age', 29), ('name', 'ehsan'), ('family', 'shirzadi')]
```

In fact, `vars` gets you a dictionary with some *unwanted* members already ommited:

```
class MyBase(object):
    def p(self):
        print vars(self)
```

or just:

```
a = UserTest(name='ehsan', family='shirzadi', age=29)
print vars(a)
```

yields:

```
{'age': 29, 'name': 'ehsan', 'family': 'shirzadi'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
class MyBase(object):
    def p(self):
        print vars(self)
```